# calling methods depending on the caller method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say I have a class:

```
class MyClass
  # In my class I have these 2 filters
  self.properties_for_create = [:p1, :p2, :p3]
  self.properties_for_update = [:p2, :p3, :p4]

  # Then I have these 2 methods
  def create(list_of_properties)
    raise TypeError, "Must be Array!" unless list_of_properties.is_a?(Array)

    # do something ...
  end

  def update(list_of_properties)
    raise TypeError, "Must be Array!" unless list_of_properties.is_a?(Array)

    # do something ...
  end
end
```

Then I want a method `my_filter_method` so that:

```
def create(list_of_properties)
  ...

  filter = my_filter_method # will return properties_for_create

  ...
end

def update(list_of_properties)
  ...

  filter = my_filter_method # will return properties_for_update

  ...
end
```

By taking any naming scheme and arguments, How should I implement this `my_filter_method` so that it looks DRY and readable?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you mean in the second part of your example. What is `arg` and what does `my_filter_method` do? Is that just excluding all properties not in the pre-defined list? If so, that's `a & b` where `a` and `b` are arrays. As a note, it's bad form to reject something out of hand just because it's not an Array. Ruby is a strong believer in duck-typing, so if your object passed in can answer all the methods you're calling on it and returns useful data, you shouldn't care what class it actually is.

Comment: In the first part, `self.properties_for_create` and `self.properties_for_update` are defined. In the second part, I want a method `my_filter_method` that takes in ANY argument and also naming scheme, so that when called in `create` returns `self.properties_for_create` and when called in `update` returns `self.properties_for_update`

Comment: @tadman and on your note about duck-typing, you mean that instead of validating the class of the object passed, I should check whether or not the object response to all the calls the method is actually sending?

Comment: Maybe my question is a bit confusing, let me update it.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're actually trying to achieve in terms of end-goals, and what the function of those two lists of properties is. What I mean by duck-typing is as a function receiving arguments it's not your responsibility to verify types. It's the responsibility of the caller to pass in something that conforms to the expectations of your method. Maybe that means supporting the `each` method, or `[]`, or `to_a`. It depends on what you need to do. Try not to freak out when someone passes you a curious object that does what you need it to do, regardless of class.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do it, but you can do it like so:

```
caller.first.scan(/`(\w+)'/).first.first
```

This will return the name of the calling method, so you can put it in `my_filter_method` and it will give you either `'create'` or `'update'`.

I should point out that I don't recommend this. This sort of convoluted meta programming is best avoided for simple situations like these.

Comment: hm ... I would agree with not using this. A user looking at this will be so confused ...